# How to fold STL container?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, fold

I need an analog of Haskell's `foldl` function to fold any STL containers. Expected signature is like following:

```
template Iterator, FoldingFunction, Result
Result foldl(
  Iterator begin, 
  Iterator end, 
  FoldingFunction f, 
  Result initValue);
```

Standard STL has no such function. Does **Boost** have any?

I know it's pretty simple to implement, but I'd like to know whether there's any ready standardized implementation.

And one more question: how do you usually fold data lists in C++/STL?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by 'fold' ??

Comment: @Konrad: [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) = reduce = accumulate.

Comment: @Konrad - process a data structure in some order and build a return value. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold

Answer (score 43, accepted):

STL does have such a function: [`std::accumulate`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/accumulate). However, it is in the header `<numeric>`, not `<algorithm>`.

Actually the [Wikipedia page on "Fold"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29#Implementation) already listed the `foldl`/`foldr` functions on most programming languages, including C++.

Comment: Note that `accumulate` uses the `value_type` of the iterator arguments for the internal accumulator variable, despite accepting and returning a distinct type, and allowing other types still in the functor argument.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I don't see this from accumulate definition:TYPE accumulate( input_iterator start, input_iterator end, TYPE val, BinaryFunction f );

Comment: @Andrey: Never mind. I was thinking of Defect Report 539 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#539). `accumulate` uses the proper internal type.

Comment: By the way, `accumulate` is a left fold; think (1 + 2) + 3 rather than 1 + (2 + 3); like `foldl` in Haskell.

Comment: @user: Use the reverse iterator for `foldr`.

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, replace `x.begin()` and `x.end()` with `x.rbegin()` and `x.rend()`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at [std::accumulate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/numeric/accumulate/) in the `<numeric>` header?

Comment: It's `std::accumulate`. It's in the `std` namespace, but in the `<numeric>` header. :)

Comment: @jalf keep 'em coming.  Only way I stay in line. :P

Answer (score 1):

here's my implementation using std::accumulate

```
template<typename collection, typename operation>
typename collection::value_type reduce(collection col, operation op)
{
    return accumulate(col.begin(),  col.end(), typename collection::value_type(), op);
}
```

the    `reduce`    means fold in Haskell. And this function template may make the program more functional :)

Comment: Using `begin(col)` and `end(col)` would be more generic but still this function is quite redundant beause `accumulate` is simple to call directly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although `std:: accumulate` seems to be the best candidate, I think that the requirement can be achieved by using good old `for_each` too.

I took the examples from the link in the [answer of KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906796/how-to-fold-stl-container/3906817#3906817), and translated all of them
to `for_each`. [The full code is posted at codepad](http://codepad.org/rqKxiifX), following is some excerpt:

```
struct result_functor {
    result_functor( int initial, int multiplier ) :
        result_( initial ), multiplier_( multiplier ) {
    }
    int operator()( int x ) {
        result_ += multiplier_ * x;
        return result_;
    }
    int result_;
    int multiplier_;
};

const int init = 100;
const int numbers[] = { 10, 20, 30 };

const int accum_sum = std::accumulate( numbers, numbers + 3, init );
const result_functor for_sum = for_each( 
    numbers, numbers + 3, result_functor( init, +1 ) );
assert( accum_sum == for_sum.result_ );
```

Comment: Stateful functor `result_functor` means undefined behavior.

Comment: @Loom This answer suggests stateful functors are fine for `std::for_each`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6113053/2348315, is it incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

why not just;

```
b_t foldl(b_t (*f)(b_t,a_t),b_t base_case,a_t * in_list){
 int l = sizeof(inList)/sizeof(a_t);
 b_t carry = base_case;
 for(int i = 0;i<l;i++){
   carry = f(carry,in_list[i]);
  }
 return carry;
}
```

or recursively; // maybe you could help me with the correct syntax...

```
b_t foldl(b_t (*f)(b_t,a_t),b_t base_case,a_t * in_list){
 return foldl(f,f(base_case,in_list[0]),in_list + 1);      
}
```

Comment: Because that only works with `b_t`, `a_t`, and function pointers. Also it is less trustworthy than the much more widely used and tested alternative that can be found in the standard library implementations.