# how to find duplicates in std::vector<string> and return a list of them?

Tags: c++, stl, functor

So if I have a vector of words like:

```
Vec1 = "words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun"
```

resulting list: **"fun", "words"**

I am trying to determine which words are duplicated, and return an alphabetized vector of 1 copy of them. My problem is that I don't even know where to start, the only thing close to it I found was `std::unique_copy` which doesn't exactly do what I need. And specifically, I am inputting a `std::vector<std::string>` but outputting a `std::list<std::string>`. And if needed, I can use functor.

Could someone at least push me in the right direction please? I already tried reading stl documentation,but I am just "brain" blocked right now.

Comment: If you use a `std::set` to store your words instead of a vector you get uniqueness and sorting thrown in for free.

Comment: Since you want it alphabetized, I assume you wouldn't mind if it was sorted?

Comment: @Rapptz well, I can make a copy of it, and then sort it, yes

Comment: @JonathanPotter then I would get "are" in the result as well, which is not what I need

Comment: @JonathanPotter Not quite "for free" ;-) It is a slower container.

Answer (score 7):

1. Make an empty `std::unordered_set<std::string>`
2. Iterator your vector, checking whether each item is a member of the set
3. If it's already in the set, this is a duplicate, so add to your result list
4. Otherwise, add to the set.

Since you want each duplicate only listed once in the results, you can use a hashset (not list) for the results as well.

Comment: `set` is a horrible idea (bad performance). `set` is for when you insert dynamically, which you don't need here. So just `sort` the `vector` and use `unique()`.

Comment: @Mehrdad it wont do the task it needs to do, which is to count duplicates, not make the vector without duplicates

Comment: @MarinaGolubtsova: I was thinking that calling `unique` once to *remove* the unique values would leave you with duplicates; calling `unique` again will remove the duplicates of those, giving you the result you need. However, it seems like `unique` actually *destroys* the rest of the array, so you'd need to modify things a bit to make it work. You still don't need `set`, though.

Comment: @MarinaGolubtsova: See my answer below.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It depends on the size of the input.  My solution's asymptotic performance is far better than sorting.

Comment: @BenVoigt: WTF, you change your answer then you tell me my comment is wrong? Also FYI, your new solution (1) requires the elements to be hashable *and* have copy-constructors, (2) isn't compatible with pre-C++11, (3) doesn't guarantee good performance, (4) requires O(N) auxiliary memory, (5) performs lots of memory allocation, which is slow in practice. Mine has none of those problems.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's not a substantive change.  If you meant to comment "Did you perhaps mean `unordered_set`?" that would have been useful, but your claims that `std::vector` is the best are simply crazy.

Comment: If it's "not a substantive change" then why did you bother to make it, just to make the claim that your *"solution's asymptotic performance is far better than sorting"*? The same wasn't true for `set`, but you made the change anyway, so you could claim that and render my comment obsolete. And I never said `vector` was the "best", I just said it was better than your solution.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What does "`set` is for when you insert dynamically" mean?  Yes I made a mistake on the name of the hashset collection, but my intent was hashset from the very beginning.  And no, `unordered_set` is not "incompatible with pre-C++11", you just need to get it from a different namespace (`boost`)

Comment: @BenVoigt: It means that you need `set` if you intend to check for duplicates *while you're adding new elements*. That's not always the case; sometimes you don't need to check for duplicates until you've *finished* adding all the items -- and the *entire point* of `std::unique` is to handle the other cases.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sure, except that `std::unique` is designed to eliminate duplicates, not return them.  And I would expect a version that works on unsorted data to use a hashset internally anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt: *"I would expect"*... why? Just because that's the only way you've seen it done? The function I wrote does exactly the same thing as `std::unique`, except it doesn't destroy the duplicates, which is sufficient for what we need.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I quote my comment: "a version that works on *unsorted* data".  Yours doesn't.  There's no comparison.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Huh? Mine calls `sort`, so obviously it works on unsorted data too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34340/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-mehrdad)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I came to chat, you were away.

Answer (score 7):

In 3 lines (not counting the vector and list creation nor the superfluous line-breaks in name of readability):

```
vector<string> vec{"words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun"};
list<string> output;

sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
set<string> uvec(vec.begin(), vec.end());
set_difference(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
               uvec.begin(), uvec.end(),
               back_inserter(output));
```

### EDIT

Explanation of the solution:

1. Sorting the vector is needed in order to use `set_difference()` later.
2. The `uvec` set will automatically keep elements sorted, and eliminate duplicates.
3. The `output` list will be populated by the elements of `vec - uvec`.

Comment: Any possible counting for this solution?

Comment: @TeodorKolev I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: for learners) [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) requires both input ranges to be already sorted. The result is also sorted.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, Ben Voigt started with a good basic idea, but I would caution against taking his wording too literally.

In particular, I dislike the idea of searching for the string in the set, then adding it to your set if it's not present, and adding it to the output if it was present. This basically means every time we encounter a new word, we search our set of existing words twice, once to check whether a word is present, and again to insert it because it wasn't. Most of that searching will be essentially identical -- unless some other thread mutates the structure in the interim (which could give a race condition).

Instead, I'd start by trying to add it to the set of words you've seen. That returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, with the `bool` set to `true` if and only if the value was inserted -- i.e., was not previously present. That lets us consolidate the search for an existing string and the insertion of the new string together into a single insert:

```
while (input >> word)
    if (!(existing.insert(word)).second)
        output.insert(word);
```

This also cleans up the flow enough that it's pretty easy to turn the test into a functor that we can then use with `std::remove_copy_if` to produce our results quite directly:

```
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class show_copies {
    std::set<std::string> existing;
public:
    bool operator()(std::string const &in) {
        return existing.insert(in).second;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words{ "words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun" };
    std::set<std::string> result;

    std::remove_copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(),
        std::inserter(result, result.end()), show_copies());

    for (auto const &s : result)
        std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Depending on whether I cared more about code simplicity or execution speed, I might use an `std::vector` instead of the `set` for result, and use `std::sort` followed by `std::unique_copy` to produce the final result. In such a case I'd probably also replace the `std::set` inside of `show_copies` with an `std::unordered_set` instead:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class show_copies {
    std::unordered_set<std::string> existing;
public:
    bool operator()(std::string const &in) {
        return existing.insert(in).second;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words{ "words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun" };
    std::vector<std::string> intermediate;

    std::remove_copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(),
        std::back_inserter(intermediate), show_copies());

    std::sort(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end());
    std::unique_copy(intermediate.begin(), intermediate.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

This is marginally more complex (one whole line longer!) but likely to be substantially faster when/if the number of words gets very large. Also note that I'm using `std::unique_copy` primarily to produce visible output. If you just want the result in a collection, you can use the standard unique/erase idiom to get unique items in `intermediate`.

Comment: A functor like this won't work correctly if it gets copied by the algorithm function.

Comment: Well yes, you use the *test-whether-it-is-present-and-make-it-present* operation.  My answer was intended to be a guide, not a 1:1 mapping to member function calls.  You can't say I chose poor methods for the details when I didn't give details.  And `existing` should probably be an `unordered_set` as well.

Comment: Any possible counting for this solution?

Comment: @TeodorKolev: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. If you want a list of unique words, and a count of each, you'd typically use a `map<string, int>`. Read words and increment the count for each. Then walk through the map and write out the words and the count for each.

Answer (score 1):

In place (no additional storage). No string copying (except to result list).  One sort + one pass:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        vector<string> vec{"words", "words", "are", "fun", "fun"};
        list<string> dup;

        sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

        const string  empty{""};
        const string* prev_p = &empty;

        for(const string& s: vec) {
                if (*prev_p==s) dup.push_back(s);
                prev_p = &s;
        }

        for(auto& w: dup) cout << w << ' '; 
        cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a pretty clean implementation using a std::map to count the occurrences, and then relying on std::list::sort to sort the resulting list of words. For example:

```
std::list<std::string> duplicateWordList(const std::vector<std::string>& words) {
    std::map<std::string, int> temp;
    std::list<std::string> ret;
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = words.begin(); iter != words.end(); ++iter) {
        temp[*iter] += 1;
        // only add the word to our return list on the second copy
        // (first copy doesn't count, third and later copies have already been handled)
        if (temp[*iter] == 2) {
            ret.push_back(*iter);
        }
    }
    ret.sort();
    return ret;
}
```

Using a std::map there seems a little wasteful, but it gets the job done.

Comment: hmm, what do you think the complexity would be then? I am trying to keep it under O(n^2), all and all, it's still better than what I had in mind >.>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better algorithm than the ones other people have proposed:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class It> It unique2(It const begin, It const end)
{
    It i = begin;
    if (i != end)
    {
        It j = i;
        for (++j; j != end; ++j)
        {
            if (*i != *j)
            { using std::swap; swap(*++i, *j); }
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("words");
    v.push_back("words");
    v.push_back("are");
    v.push_back("fun");
    v.push_back("words");
    v.push_back("fun");
    v.push_back("fun");
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(v.begin(), unique2(v.begin(), v.end()));
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(unique2(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());
}
```

It's better because it only requires `swap` with no auxiliary `vector` for storage, which means it will behave optimally for earlier versions of C++, and it doesn't require elements to be copyable.

If you're more clever, I think you can avoid sorting the vector twice as well.

Comment: What makes an algorithm *better* to you?  `O(N lg N)` complexity when an `O(N)` solution exists is *better*?

Comment: @BenVoigt: (1) asymptotic performance, (2) empirical performance, (3) the requirements imposed on the caller (e.g. no need for copy constructors, exception-safety), (4) need for auxiliary memory (mine doesn't need to store copies of the input). In any case, your solution also uses `set`, so it's `O(N log N)` too, except that `set` has far worse empirical performance than `vector`, making this solution better.