# Having trouble checking for duplicates in a vector

Tags: c++, loops

This is my chunk of code. I am trying to loop through the vector and if there is a duplicate I want to output "Each number must be different". The problem is when the vector elements are not the same it still outputs "Each number must be different." What am I doing wrong?

```
bool endLoop = false;
        for(int g = 0; g < guessVec.size(); ++g){
            for( int j = 1; j < guessVec.size(); ++j){
                if(guessVec.at(g) == guessVec.at(j)){
                    endLoop = true;
                }
                else if( guessVec.at(g) != guessVec.at(j)){
                    endLoop = false;
                }
            }
            if(endLoop){
                cout << "Each number must be different.";
                break;
        }
```

Comment: By _sorting_ prior to looking for dups you'd save a lot of effort. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892896/how-to-find-duplicates-in-stdvectorstring-and-return-a-list-of-them for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bool endLoop = false;
    for(int g = 0; g < guessVec.size(); ++g)
    {
        for(int j = g + 1; j < guessVec.size(); ++j) //<-- j can start from 'g + 1'
        {
            if(guessVec.at(g) == guessVec.at(j))
            {
                endLoop = true;
                break; //<-- you can break the loop once you discovered a duplicate
            }

            //else if( guessVec.at(g) != guessVec.at(j))
            //{             
            //    endLoop = false;
            //}

        }

        if(endLoop == true)
        {
            cout << "Each number must be different.";
            break;
        }
    }
```