# How to find multiple elements in an std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, find, wstring

I'm having issues trying to find multiple of the same element in a vector. I would like to find duplicate elements every 3 indexes. If there is a duplicate the next 2 elements go into a new vector.

```
std::vector<std::wstring> wsBuf = {"one" , "three", "five", "two", "one","ten", "nine"};`
std::vector<std::wstring> wsWriteFile;
for(DWORD i = 0; i < wsBuf.size(); ++i)
{
  std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator it = wsReadFile.begin(); //wsReadFile has an enumerated list
  it = std::find(it, wsReadFile.end(), wsBuf[i]);
  if(it != wsReadFile.end())
  {
    DWORD index = std::distance(wsReadFile.begin(), it);
    if(index < wsReadFile.size())
    {
       wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index];
       wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index + 1];
       wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index + 2];
    }
  }
}
```

This will only find the zero index but not the second. Does anyone have any idea how to find the second index with C++11 functions?

I found a way to do it without c++11 functions

```
`for(DWORD i = 0; i < wsBuf.size(); ++i)
 { 
   DWORD j = 0;
   do
   {
     if(wsBuf[i] == wsReadFile[j])
     {
       wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index];
       wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index + 1];
       wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index + 2];
     }
     j+=3;
   }while(j < wsReadFile.size());
}`
```

Comment: If you want to *remove* duplicates, then `std::sort` the vector and then [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) has you covered. But it's not quite clear from your question *exactly* what you want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find duplicates in std::vector<string> and return a list of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892896/how-to-find-duplicates-in-stdvectorstring-and-return-a-list-of-them)

Comment: @JesperJuhl sorry for the confusion I have edited my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `wsBuf`, you only call `find` once.  This clearly finds ... one element.

```
it = std::find(it, wsReadFile.end(), wsBuf[i]);
if(it != wsReadFile.end())
{
  DWORD index = std::distance(wsReadFile.begin(), it);
  if(index < wsReadFile.size())
  {
     wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index];
     wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index + 1];
     wsWriteFile.push_back(wsReadFile[index + 2];
  }
}
```

It also doesn't compile, you are missing some `)`s.  In the future, post code that compiles and demonstrates the problem; if you don't know the problem, you cannot know what doesn't matter to solving it.

In any case, you need a loop.  I'd also want bounds checking.  And less iterator<->index conversion.  And fewer types that don't matter.

```
auto it = std::find(wsReadFile.begin(), wsReadFile.end(), wsBuf[i]);
while(it != wsReadFile.end())
{
  auto left = std::distance(it, wsReadFile.end());
  // don't copy past the end:
  auto copy_end = it+(std::min)(left, decltype(left)(3));
  std::copy( it, copy_end, std::back_inserter(wsWriteFile) );
  // find next:
  it = std::find( copy_end, wsReadFile.end(), wsBuf[i]);
}
```