# how to convert std::vector to std::set without losing the order

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdvector, stdset

I am using the below code for conversion:

```
std::set<ObjectType> s(v.begin(), v.end());
```

However, I need to keep the order of the vector elements. How can I do this?

Comment: The *only reason* to use a `set` is that it is *ordered*. If you wanted to keep the order of elements in the `vector`, you should keep the elements in the `vector`.

Comment: `std::unique` may be the think you want instead of `std::set`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I was thiking of suggesting that but `std::unique` requires the container is sorted.

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Also, I need to eliminate dublicate values. This is why I am converting vector to set.

Comment: Boost::Multiindex may be a solution using a sequenced index and a unique index.

Comment: So, your question might be: How to eliminate duplicates of an unsorted vector without loosing the order of elements?

Comment: No, not only duplicate values, also I need std::set type.

Comment: @eaytan Why do you need the `std::set`?

Answer (score 4):

You can't if the vector is not ordered.  A [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) keeps it contents in either an ascending or descending order.

If the vector is ordered then you just need to set the comparison function of the `std::set` to whatever was used to order the vector.

You may want to see: [How to remove duplicates from unsorted std::vector while keeping the original ordering using algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200486/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-unsorted-stdvector-while-keeping-the-original-or)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if and only if your `vector` is sorted by some strict weak ordering, e.g. sorted by `<` for numbers. In that case, give the `set` the appropriate comparison object (the one you used to sort your `vector`) and the order will fit.

Otherwise, if your `vector` was not sorted by a fitting criterion, you cannot make the `set` keep the original order as sorting the elements is one of the invariants of the `set`.